Publishing to Maven repository hosted by Google Artifact Registry is failing
We are currently using Gradle 8.7 and its built-in maven-publish plugin, and we are getting the following error when running the publish task:
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException: start tag not allowed in epilog but got v (position: END_TAG seen ...</metadata>\n    <v... @13:7) 
  at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.parseEpilog(MXParser.java:1959)
  at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.nextImpl(MXParser.java:1696)
  at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.next(MXParser.java:1319)
  at org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.metadata.io.xpp3.MetadataXpp3Reader.read(MetadataXpp3Reader.java:958)
  at org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.metadata.io.xpp3.MetadataXpp3Reader.read(MetadataXpp3Reader.java:557)
  at org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.metadata.io.xpp3.MetadataXpp3Reader.read(MetadataXpp3Reader.java:586)
  at org.gradle.api.publish.maven.internal.publisher.AbstractMavenPublisher.lambda$readExistingMetadata$1(AbstractMavenPublisher.java:152)

Here are some information about the current setup:

We are publishing to two remote Maven repositories hosted in Google Artifact Registry. We are publishing both Java and JS packages, so there are two tasks that get run when the publish task runs:  publishMavenJavaPublicationToMavenRepository and publishJsPublicationToMavenRepository. One repository is for SNAPSHOT packages, and the other one is for RELEASES.
Our publish task always succeed when we run our PR builds, which publish snapshot packages. But in our main, which runs the same task with the same argument, just pointing to a different repository, it always fail with this exact error. Both PR and main builds are running in Jenkins.

Now on to the behaviors:

Sometimes publishMavenJavaPublicationToMavenRepository fails, sometimes publishJsPublicationToMavenRepository fails, but either results in publish task to fail.
When publishJsPublicationToMavenRepository fails, we do see the JS packages published to the repository. However, it short-circuited the rest of the build. The same goes for the corresponding Java task. And inspecting the published pom.xml file, it looks correct to me.

We do see this issue when we run the publish task for the main-branch locally on my machine, though it doesn't happen as consistent as when running in Jenkins.
Lots of internet searches suggest that there could be concurrency issues with multiple processes modifying the maven-metadata.xml files but we do not have parallel turned on for the Gradle task.
Am I missing something here? Has anyone run into this issue before?

Making sure that parallel is not turned on for the publish task.
Inspecting the content of pom.xml file of the published content to make sure nothing looks off.

